# How to add buttons next to select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to add close `button` to clear select element in `select` tag, as well as I need to make the `dropdown` like a `button` as below image
[image]

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="sel1">Select Asset:</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="assetCategory">
      <option value="" selected disabled>Select Asset</option>
      <option value="1">Asset 1</option>
      <option value="2">Asset 2</option>
      <option value="3">Asset 3</option>
      <option value="4">Asset 4</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

How can I do this? Or is it not possible to do?

Comment: Please share you code, till now whatever you have tried.

Comment: I'm voting to close this thread as no code has been given

Comment: @Ivan I'll update the code with what i have done so far

Comment: you need dropdown as a button or maybe just custom icon instead of arrow? As far as I know there are no cross-browser solution to expand select with JS

Comment: @Ivan fiddle link added

Answer (score 3):

You have to style the `select` tag the way it looks on your image.
The cancel button must be a seperat HTML Tag, which than have to be styled on its own and positioned next to the select.

Your html would look something like this:

```html
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<button>X</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with ease using bootstrap and JQuery. However the logic remains the same if you choose something else. Check the snippet below:

```js
$("#clear_addon").on("click", function(){
  $("#target_select").val("");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="input-group">
  <select class="form-control" id="target_select">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
  </select>
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="clear_addon">Clear</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to a the `button` to `select` tag not for `input` tag

Comment: sorry, didn't notice that. Update my answer

Comment: Is it possible to change the select (arrow) button ?

Comment: yes, it's possible with various css and js tricks, for example:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37834481/7732200 .
I can apply it to the snippet above if you want, but not sure that it remains reusable and illustrative - solutions I know are really tricky

Answer (score 2):

Try something like following:

```js
$("#clear_addon").on("click", function(){
  $("select").val("");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="input-group">
  <select class="form-control"  aria-describedby="clear-addon">
  <option></option>
  <option>option1</option>
  <option>option2</option>
  </select>
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="clear_addon">&#10006;</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

some ugly but it might give a idea look

```js
$("button").click(function(){
 $("#a").val('');
});
```

```css
select {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

button {
  position:fixed;
  left:158px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color:white;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
div select, button{
  height:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select id="a">
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="c">b</option>
    <option value="c">c</option>
  </select>
  <button>remove</button>
</div>
```