# Can't seem to recreate this filter dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I've been trying to recreate this wireframe for a couple hours now, but I just can't get it to look the same and work properly.

[image]

I've tried to do it with the select tag, but this doesn't allow me to style the options without something like jQuery. I just want this to be as simple as possible, it really doesn't need to be flashy in any way.

Does anyone know how I can recreate this filter menu? Preferably without Java, but if that's not possible than so be it.

Comment: You can't style a `select` element like this. Either use some plugin, or you have to build this select using `div`s etc, and write functionality using javascript.
This is due to browser limitations you will find on all major browsers.

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37833573/how-to-change-bootstrap-select-arrows-to-glyphicon
Someone already did that.

Comment: Is utilizing the select tag the only way to create a filter dropdown menu? At the stage I'm at in HTML & CSS I really don't feel the need to dive into complicated plugins yet. This feels and looks like something so basic that I can't believe it's so difficult to recreate

Comment: You can create a disabled input field and place a button inside it. Then use a div and animate it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the basic idea of how to achieve this:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="dropdown-header">
    <a href="#">Amount</a>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-body">
    <div>
      <a href="#">Option 1</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#">Option 2</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="#">Option 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS:** (I'm using jQuery here, but you can do the same with pure js)

```
$(function() {
  $(".dropdown-header a").click(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().next().toggle();
  });
});
```

**CSS:** (Modify to achieve the desired view. You may also need to edit some properties dynamically with js)

```
.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown,
.dropdown-header {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.dropdown-header,
.dropdown-body div {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Looks more like it, but isn't this just a way to recreate it visually, instead of it actually being a filter menu? I'm just trying to do the front-end part, so it doesn't actually have to function properly, but still. I don't want it to be "hacky", if you catch my drift. Thank you, regardless

Comment: This is just "skeleton" of what you need. You can add any functionality with JS, like filtering on click, or staying selected until next actions or smth else.

Answer (score 0):

You can style select. But you can't do this with the options.

```css
.select {
border-radius: 15px;
outline:0;
}
```

```html
<select class="select">
<option>Option 1</option>
<option class="option2">Option 2</option>
</select>
```