# How can I made this kind of form select menu using bootstrap 4?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, form-helpers, bootstrap-form-helper

I am trying to change the custom bootstrap default form selector arrow. Is there any way to change the default arrow in the form and add this `<i class=" fas fa-caret-down"></i>` caret down icon?

Comment: I'd say this is already answered in the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37833573/how-to-change-bootstrap-select-arrows-to-glyphicon question.

This is the code example taken from the answer of the question above:
http://codepen.io/blonfu/pen/EyyPpJ

Answer (score 1):

`.custom-select` is the class that add this icon as a `background`

So you can download the `SVG` and override the class and it should work.

am sure there is a better way than that. But it's the only way I could think of at the moment.

[image]

```
.custom-select {
    background: url('../images/caret-down-solid.svg') no-repeat right .75rem center/8px 10px;

}
```